# Image uploading testing using phpunit and mockery

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.1, mockery

I'm trying to test the image uploading using Laravel and PhpUnit. Outside the test class, it's working fine. But when I run the test, I'm getting the following error:

> 1) App\UploadTest::it_uploads_an_image_on_post
>   Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException: No matching handler
>   found for
>   Mockery_0_Symfony_Component_HttpFoundation_File_UploadedFile::move("posts/photos",
>   "/nowfoo.jpg"). Either the method was unexpected or its argumen ts
>   matched no expected argument list for this method

and my Test file is:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Mockery as m;
use App\BBImage;

class UploadTest extends \TestCase
{

    /**
     * @test
     */

    public function it_uploads_an_image_on_post()
    {
        $file = m::mock(UploadedFile::class, [
            'getClientOriginalName'      => 'foo',
            'getClientOriginalExtension' => 'jpg'
        ]);


        $file->shouldReceive('move')
            ->once()
            ->with('posts/photos', 'nowfoo.jpg');


        $photo = new BBImage($file);


        $this->assertEquals('posts/photos/nowfoo.jpg', $photo->makePhoto());


    }

}

function time() { return 'now'; }

function sha1($path) {return $path;}
```

and my BBImage.php class

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class BBImage
{

    protected $file;

    public function __construct(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }


    public function makePhoto()
    {

        $path = 'posts/photos';

        $name = $this->makeFileName();

        $this->file->move($path, $name);

        return ('/'.$path.$name);
    }



    protected function makeFileName()
    {

        $name = sha1(
            time() . $this->file->getClientOriginalName()
        );

        $extension = $this->file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        return "/$name.$extension";

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is just a typo. You should change the expectation:

```
$file->shouldReceive('move')
        ->once()
        ->with('posts/photos', 'nowfoo.jpg');
```

To this:

```
$file->shouldReceive('move')
        ->once()
        ->with('posts/photos', '/nowfoo.jpg');
```